# Mocking a context using Moq

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

Upon debugging a request, I see that the object type passed to is of type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext` which I'm trying to mock here in a unit test, which for some reason is not instantiable.

screenshot:
[image: screenshot] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hag1d.png

```
 app.Run(async context =>
 {

 });
```

**Unit test**

```
var contextMock = new Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext>();
```

error:
[image: error]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to mock that class.

You can create an instance of `DefaultHttpContext`

```
HttpContext context = new DefaultHttpContext();
context.Request.Path = new PathString("path here");

//...
```

or just mock `HttpContext` is you want to mock specific features.

```
Mock<HttpContext> contextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();

//...setup
var path = new PathString("path here");
contextMock.Setup(_ => _.Request.Path).Returns(path);

HttpContext context = contextMock.Object;
```

The former is simpler and requires very little setup.